# mediasoup installation failed on windows with a meson error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mediasoup

```
npm ERR! code 1

npm ERR! path C:\Users\USER\Documents\video-conferencing\node_modules\mediasoup 

npm ERR! command failed

npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node npm-scripts.js postinstall

npm ERR! npm-scripts.js [INFO] running task "postinstall"

npm ERR! npm-scripts.js [INFO] executing command: node npm-scripts.js worker:build
npm ERR! npm-scripts.js [INFO] running task "worker:build"
npm ERR! npm-scripts.js [INFO] executing command: make -C worker

npm ERR! # Updated pip and setuptools are needed for meson

npm ERR! make: Leaving directory `/c/Users/USER/Documents/video-conferencing/node_modules/mediasoup/worker'

npm ERR! make: dirname: Command not found

npm ERR! make: Entering directory `/c/Users/USER/Documents/video-conferencing/node_modules/mediasoup/worker'

npm ERR! make: pwd: Command not found

npm ERR! make: pwd: Command not found

npm ERR! make: /bin/sh: Command not found
npm ERR! make: pwd: Command not found
npm ERR! make: /bin/sh: Command not found
npm ERR! make: pwd: Command not found
npm ERR! make: /bin/sh: Command not found
npm ERR! make: pwd: Command not found
npm ERR! make: /bin/sh: Command not found
npm ERR! make: pwd: Command not found
npm ERR! make: /bin/sh: Command not found
npm ERR! make: *** [meson-ninja] Error 127
```

Please Help

Comment: DUDE I AM GETTING THIS TOO